# Laravel Nova storing original file name in the database and in local storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm having an issue with storing the original file name both in the database and in disk storage. The file saves correctly in the database and in the Nova backend, but in the disk storage is just saves as a random string.

In the database: `my-user-friendly-file-name.pdf`

In the disk storage: `kfnakfncanjnaskdmkasniodanwjioeocniosandoaisndcacs.pdf`

I have followed the docs, and it seems the below code should work but it doesn't.

```
File::make('Attachment PDF Upload', 'attachment_url')
    ->rules('file')
    ->disk('attachments')
    ->storeOriginalName('attachment_url')
    ->storeAs(function(Request $request) {
        return sha1($request->attachment_url->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . pathinfo($request->attachment_url->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}),
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Leave it be. It's intentionally that way, to avoid overwriting someone else's upload with the same filename. There's no reason to worry about the name it's stored as.

Comment: All the other models with file uploads I have left be, but this is for controlling email attachments and I wanted more human-friendly attachment names.

Comment: You can still do that. Store the original name in a different column. In your Mailable, `->attach('/path/to/file', ['as' => $foo->original_name])`. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#attachments.

Comment: Great! I will add another column and work on that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just as @ceejayoz said I ended up storing an extra column for the original file name and then call that in your code where needed, in my case emailing out attachments.

```
File::make('Attachment PDF Upload', 'attachment_url')
    ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
        return [
            'attachment_url' => $request->attachment_url->store('/', 'attachments'),
            'attachment_original_name' => $request->attachment_url->getClientOriginalName(),
        ];
    }),
```

Then simply attach like this:

```
$message->attach($attachment->attachment_url, ['as' => $attachment->attachment_original_name]);
```